# How to set root directory to a subfolder (local php development environment)

Tags: apache, relative-path, virtualhost, directory-structure

I'm just starting to learn web dev, but got myself a bit confused when setting up my local development environment.

I had a php site on shared hosting for some time. I would edit local files and upload them, then refresh to ensure everything worked. A naughty practice I know!

So I have tried to set up a local dev environment and installed AMPPS for a local webserver (PHP5).
I have ambitiously set up the folder structure below so that I can code up a range of websites to try out different languages and frameworks whilst keeping them all seperate. *(Square brackets denote folders)*. Note sure if this is the correct approach... (?)

```
-->[PHP]
---> [AMPPS]
----> [www]
-----> [PROJECTS]

------> [project_name]
-------> index.php
-------> .htaccess
-------> [images]
-------> [section1]
--------> page1.php
-------> [etc...]

------> [project_name]
------> [project_name]
--> [RUBY]
--> [PYTHON]
```

My first hurdle however is that all of my links were relative, and I had of course uploaded my site at root with my host. Root in my local dev enironment is now `www`, which as you can see is several folders up from where I have installed my site.

Links (e.g. `<a href="/section1/page1.php">Page 1</a>`) now display as: `"localhost/section1/page1.php"` when I believe they should in fact show as `"localhost/PROJECTS/project_name/section1/page1.php"`.

I don't think that telling APACHE that my root directory is [project_name] is the correct approach, because then it wont work for other projects I create. I assume that I should be doing something on a project by project basis to specify it's own root directory.

I thought that I could specify root by adding an `.htaccess` file to the `project_name` folder:

From my online research I thought it would go something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /PROJECTS/project_name/
```

or perhaps

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ .;C/PHP/AMPSS/www/PROJECTS/project_name/
```

However I can't get these to work.

When the site was online, I had also coded `<?php set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); //Look for includes starting from ROOT location ?>` at the top every page, thinking I was doing the right thing.
Now I am not so sure that I correctly understood what I was doing there. It doesn't seem to have any impact with or without it in my development environment. And I haven't been able to edit it in any way successfully to resolve my relative links issue.

Sorry for the long post.

I'm grateful for any and all feedback/assistance. Thanks in advance :)

[Resolved] - The advice below was perfect. Thank you all. :)

A tip for Chrome users:
If you are using a custom domain, like I did with .dev, either proceed the address with `http://`, or end it with a trailing `/`.
For example I now visit my dev site in Chrome by visiting projectname.dev/ (without the last / it tries to search).

At first I thought I had set up VirtualHost or hosts incorrectly, when in reality it was this Chrome behaviour that that was clouding the issue. At the time of writing, other browsers like Firefox don't share this concern.
Hope that helps someone else out.

Comment: You are probably looking for setting up multiple virtual host names instead. (See `/etc/hosts` and `<VirtualHostName>`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up Apache for local development/testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118423/set-up-apache-for-local-development-testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that configuring Apache for each project is the way forward. It's best done with [virtual hosts](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Configuring-and-Using-Virtual-Hosts-in-Apache/). Define a virtual host for each project and give it a domain name or subdomain for development. In my case I use `test.com` for all my local development and configure `project1.test.com`, `project2.test.com` etc so all my relative paths work as expected. For this I also [edit my `hosts` file](http://practice.chatserve.com/hosts.html) so the DNS lookup for `test.com` and sub projects resolve to my local machine.

Rewriting URLs is something I reserve for a project-by-project basis, without setting global rewrites for a specific server setup. That way my local development environment is close to the actual server environment and project-specific rewrites will work as expected.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your info.
In particular Tak & Mario, as I went with the VirtualHost recommendation. Never heard of it before but it sounds exactly like what I need.

After getting caught out by Chrome sending my test.dev link to search, rather than via hosts as I intended, I have had some success in Firefox. 
However having more than one VirtualHost listing in httpd.conf is causing it to default to the first one. And AMPSS seems not to like it, and wont allow Apache to start until I restore the default file.
I'm sure I can iron out the wrinkles though. Thank again for the big help :)

Comment: Don't forget the `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive when setting up vhosts. On some stacks (i.e. XAMPP) it's commented. Enable it.

Comment: Thx newermind! I also had made the mistake of using \ instead of / in my path filenames. Everything working perfectly now. :)

(I have updated main question with a tip for Chrome too)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using method mentioned by @Tak, but I know there might be problems with pre-configured WAMP packs to add virtual hosts, so there is also a solution to use [BASE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag in head section of your html:

```
<base href="http://localhost/PROJECTS/project_name/">
```